# Erro NotSupportedException ao setar valor a um DataSource

Tags: c#

Tenho um textBox e quero que, ao digitar algo, o dataSource do meu gridFornecedor seja atualizado.

Estou usando o código abaixo:

```
private void txtNome_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridFornecedor.DataSource = modelOff.fornecedors.Where(p => p.nome.Contains(txtNome.Text));
}
```

Recebo o erro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema tá escrito no erro, o retorno da sua expressão é uma *query* e não dados concretos.

Chame `.ToList()` para materializar os dados

```
gridFornecedor.DataSource = modelOff.fornecedors
                                    .Where(p => p.nome.Contains(txtNome.Text)).ToList();
```

Perceba que usando o evento `TextChanged` você está fazendo com que os dados sejam buscados no banco a **cada tecla que o usuário pressionar**. Isso pode ser extremamente problemático se existir um número considerável de dados. Talvez seja uma boa ideia pensar um pouco melhor e fazer de uma forma mais apropriada.

Comment: Como você sugere que eu faça a busca no banco? Clicando num botão? Faço assim porque é mais interativo.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor. Entenda que eu só te alertei porque **pode ser um problema**, não quer dizer que já seja. Se você sabe que o tráfego de dados não vai ser grande e isso não será problema, mantenha assim mesmo =D

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa materializar o retorno dos dados do banco através de uma conversão para um objeto ou coleção. Seguindo a sugestão da mensagem de erro, tente chamar o método `ToList()` depois de aplicar o `Where`:

```
private void txtNome_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridFornecedor.DataSource = modelOff.fornecedors.Where(p => p.nome.Contains(txtNome.Text)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Materializar todos os dados para depois filtrar?

Comment: A ordem do ToList() estava errada mesmo, já corrigi.